# Bash string comparison of two identical strings false?

Tags: macos, bash

Hello I have the following script:

```
#! /bin/bash
 Output=$(defaults read com.apple.systemuiserver menuExtras | grep Bluetooth.menu)
Check="\"/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu\","
echo $Output
echo $Check
     if [ "$Output" = "$Check" ]
    then
           echo "OK"
else
    echo "FALSE" 
    echo "Security Compliance Setting 'Show Bluetooth Status in Menu Bar(2.1.3)' has been changed!" | logger

fi
```

When you run it, both variables have the exact same output however the check always says it is FALSE

here is the out put from my terminal:

```
"/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu",
"/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu",
FALSE
```

Any idea why it is not detecting that they are the same?

Comment: Use `echo "[$Output]"` and `echo "[$Check]"`

Comment: Or `declare -p Output Check`.

Comment: Or `printf '%q\n' "$Output" "$Check"`.

Comment: I suspect that Output contains leading spaces, that can't be seen by OP with _unquoted_ (horror!) `echo $Output`, so OP is very confused. OP should learn how to properly use quotes. But I'm just assuming. OP should learn how to properly use quotes anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone in the comments suspected, the problem is whitespace in $Output (which `echo $Output` removes); specifically, 4 leading spaces (note that in the following, "$ " is my shell prompt):

```
$ defaults read com.apple.systemuiserver menuExtras | grep Bluetooth.menu
    "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu",
$ Output=$(defaults read com.apple.systemuiserver menuExtras | grep Bluetooth.menu)
$ echo $Output
"/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu",
$ echo "[$Output]"
[    "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu",]
$ Check="    \"/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu\","
$ if [ "$Output" = "$Check" ]; then echo "OK"; else echo "FALSE"; fi
OK
```

Note that since the number of spaces might not always be the same, it might be safer to use bash's wildcard matching capability within a `[[ ]]` conditional expression (this *will not work* with `[ ]`):

```
$ Check="\"/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu\","
$ if [[ "$Output" = *"$Check" ]]; then echo "OK"; else echo "FALSE"; fi
OK
```

You could also skip the string comparison entirely, and just use the fact that `grep` returns a success status only if it finds a match:

```
#!/bin/bash
if defaults read com.apple.systemuiserver menuExtras | grep -q "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu"; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "FALSE" 
    echo "Security Compliance Setting 'Show Bluetooth Status in Menu Bar(2.1.3)' has been changed!" | logger
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for you amazing answer Gordon! It is much appreciated!